# Sending notification to Azure Notification Hub from Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app

Tags: c#, azure, notifications, win-universal-app, azure-notificationhub

As the title suggests, I need to send a notification **FROM** a UWP app (written in C#) to my Azure's hub (and from there it's sent to an Android app that I've already created). I obviously use GCM in order to send push notification to my Android app.

After countless hours of searching I have yet to find a single tutorial that would somehow be of use, since most of them use a console application in order to send the notification, not a Universal Windows Platform app.

If anyone  could please help me I'd be *really* thankful.

Comment: Could you show the code you use? Sending a push notification via  c# is always the same... regardless if you use UWP, WPF, Forms or a console app.

Comment: @HeribertScharnagl Gladly. Here's the link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/  ... And for my android app I've used this one: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/  ... All I need to do is basically translating the functions that are below "(Optional) Send push notifications directly from the app" in that link to C#. But the problem is that I've never wrote a code in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question here since a lot of people struggled with this like me. So here's a code that sends a notification from a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) through an Azure Notification Hub, to an Android app (using GCM).

Please note that **MUST slightly change the code** for it to work on **your own** notification hub (see the comments in the code for more details)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


namespace SendNotification
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.sendNotification();
        }

        string Endpoint = "";
        string SasKeyName = "";
        string SasKeyValue = "";

        public void ConnectionStringUtility(string connectionString)
        {
            //Parse Connectionstring
            char[] separator = { ';' };
            string[] parts = connectionString.Split(separator);
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (parts[i].StartsWith("Endpoint"))
                    Endpoint = "https" + parts[i].Substring(11);
                if (parts[i].StartsWith("SharedAccessKeyName"))
                    SasKeyName = parts[i].Substring(20);
                if (parts[i].StartsWith("SharedAccessKey"))
                    SasKeyValue = parts[i].Substring(16);
            }
        }


        public string getSaSToken(string uri, int minUntilExpire)
        {
            string targetUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(uri.ToLower()).ToLower();

            // Add an expiration in seconds to it.
            long expiresOnDate = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            expiresOnDate += minUntilExpire * 60 * 1000;
            long expires_seconds = expiresOnDate / 1000;
            String toSign = targetUri + "\n" + expires_seconds;

            // Generate a HMAC-SHA256 hash or the uri and expiration using your secret key.
            MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
            BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
            var messageBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(toSign, encoding);
            IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(SasKeyValue, encoding);
            CryptographicKey hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
            IBuffer signedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBuffer);

            string signature = Uri.EscapeDataString(CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signedMessage));

            return "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + targetUri + "&sig=" + signature + "&se=" + expires_seconds + "&skn=" + SasKeyName;
        }


        public async void sendNotification()
        {
            //insert your HubFullAccess here (a string that can be copied from the Azure Portal by clicking Access Policies on the Settings blade for your notification hub)
            ConnectionStringUtility("YOURHubFullAccess"); 

            //replace YOURHUBNAME with whatever you named your notification hub in azure 
            var uri = Endpoint + "YOURHUBNAME" + "/messages/?api-version=2015-01";
            string json = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"" + "Hello World!" + "\"}}";


            //send an HTTP POST request
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
                request.Content = new StringContent(json);

                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", getSaSToken(uri, 1000));
                request.Headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Format", "gcm");
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Notification Hub REST APIs to push a notification from anywhere (backend or device) over vanilla HTTP/HTTPS.

There is a sample (using a Java client) here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495628.aspx

And the API reference is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495827.aspx